# Onclick event bubbling

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me out with stopping bubble effect on onclick events?

I got this:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function1(){
    alert('test');
  }
  function2(){
    alert('test');
  }
</script>
<div onclick="function1()">
  <span onclick="function2()">test</span>
  blablablabla
</div>
```

Now when I click the span, I don't want function 1 to start, but just function 2. How to do this? Do I have to edit the function, or add some more global java to this?

Comment: "global java" - Java is _not_ Javascript. Don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 5):

Change your attachment of `function2` to be like this:

```
<span onclick="function2(event)">
```

Then, within the function:

```
function function2(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
 }
```

What we're doing there:

1. Giving the function visibility of the event object (by passing it in from the `onclick`.
2. Telling it not to bubble, either by using `stopPropagation` (DOM standard) or `cancelBubble` (IE-specific)

---

A lot of this stuff can be made simpler by using a decent JavaScript/DOM library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). These smooth-over browser differences, etc.